# merge two mobile modem connections into a single wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

My brother has presented me with the following problem, which I am not able to help with: he has two 4G modems, each using a different mobile provider. At the moment, they each create their own wifi network and he says that one is faster but unstable, and the other slow but more stable. (And, therefore, neither is really usable for video meetings, a requirement in these corona times...)

What he asked me was whether there is a way to "merge" these two connections, so that computers would see it as a single wifi network that would utilize the two connections in an (close to) optimal way?

Is it at all possible and if so, what kind of hardware and software would he need?

Comment: Check OpenMPTCPRouter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As intimated by @music2myear this is a major undertaking. It may be possible, although the connection/throughput management are very difficult. If you are not proficient at networking then this us likely a non-starter. In short, this is likely not practical.

The general solution requires a highly customised environment.  You can produce this with a core router which can run OpenVPN (or possibly other VPN software). Depending on your need/performance profile you may also need channel bonding. You may also need source routing.

You will then need an external server which us your endpoint - this will run OpenVPN and possibly channel bonding as well. This server needs to handle NAT, and all data gets routed through it.  You need to disable reverse path filtering on both sides.

The idea being you backhaul the data across the openvpn connection(s) and because you control both ends you can balance/bond/control which of the links is used.

You will need source routing on your client as you need traffic to traverse the VPN(s) through different gateways. You might be able to get round this limitation if you give the VPN server 2 real-world addresses.

If you want to use both channels at the same time you will need to do some kind if channel bonding on the VPN connections.You will need 2/VPN connections up simultaneously - 1 via each connection.

You will likely need to write some kind if monitoring software to modify the load balancing depending on the state of the low high bandwidth, low quality connection.

None of this is nice.  The closest I've seen to this is helping an small Wireless ISP bind 2 DSL channels together to get double the backhaul using OpenVPN to aggregate channels  This worked reasonably well for a shortish term fix until they could get proper connectivity, but they did not need to contend with different line characteristics for balancing.

Answer (score 1):

Load Balancing is the term for what you are looking for.

However, you cannot do what you're asking. Load balancing in your scenario routes traffic based on which link is more available, less saturated, but each individual stream has to go over a single link. So, an online meeting would be routed over just one of the available connections, not split over both, but another piece of network traffic MAY be routed over the other connection if it was more "open".

It will not split the web meeting traffic over both connections.

I believe there are software products that will do this, but they require hardware that supports it, and the average computer wireless radio can only connect to a single wireless network at a time. There are hardware based network load balancers designed to work with cellular internet services, but these tend to be quite expensive enterprise class devices, and not at all appropriate for an average home user.

Answer (score 0):

No. They're two distinct devices, distinct SSID's.